# VS Code python snippets are not working in my vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using VS Code from a week and I want to use VS Code built-in Python snippets but it is not working for me. I've tried JS snippets and it is working fine in VS Code but Python snippets are not working.

**Image links:**

JS Snippet:
[image]
PY snippet:
[image]

Comment: you mean code auto completion?

Comment: I've added 2 images for clarification please check them. Snippets are working for js but not for py.

Comment: In VS Code, the auto-completion function of python code is provided by the extension pyhon and language service. At present, it supports more prompts of a single code instead of auto-completion of snippets.

Answer (score 16):

Found the answer:

It seems they decided to remove code snippets from the python extension in the last update:
[changelog in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fc8I.png)

They may be added back in the future but for now i would suggest just using the python snippets extention: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=frhtylcn.pythonsnippets

Comment: If you want the exact old snippets because you're used to them (like I was) they can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/2020.12.424452561/snippets/python.json) and added to your user snippets.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install the Python extension for VS Code from the Visual Studio Marketplace([Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python))
2. To verify that you've installed Python successfully on your machine, run one of the following commands (depending on your operating system):

Linux/macOS: open a Terminal Window and type the following command:

```
python3 --version
```

Windows: open a command prompt and run the following command:

```
py -3 --version
```

3. From within VS Code, select a Python 3 interpreter by opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), start typing the Python: Select Interpreter command to search, then select the command. You can also use the Select Python Environment option on the Status Bar if available (it may already show a selected interpreter, too)

Refer to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) article for more information